# OpenCV vs 3rd party face recognition SDKs

Tags: opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I'm looking to implement face recognition feature and I see OpenCV is capable of it: https://github.com/Mjrovai/OpenCV-Face-Recognition

At the same time, I see many 3rd party face verification SDKs, like
http://kairos.com, http://www.neurotechnology.com/face-verification.html, http://ever.ai, etc. In general practise, what's the difference between OpenCV and 3rd party ones, if you only need offline face-recognition with no fancy addons, and which shall be used?

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked with OpenCV uses a method (LBP) to perform the face-recognition that is outdated at the state of the art and that I think can hardly lead you to excellent results.

The SDKs you talk about are paid, and since they are obviously not open-source and I can not know what technologies they use.

If you prefer to implement a good face-recognition yourself, you have to use OpenCV only for the image capture / video stream part and then use something like TensorFlow/Keras/PyTorch for the deep learning part.

Comment: do you know any paid SDK for face recognition/verification that supports offline mode?

Comment: No, I don't. But i'm not an expert in that field, more in the implementation.